# Suggestion for a book on cryptography

Tags: cryptography

Can someone suggest me a good book on cryptography with a lot of solved examples.

Comment: As a benchmark for suggestions, have you checked Ch. 9 of http://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Number-Theory-Applications-Edition/dp/0123724872 or Ch. 7-- of http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540691990, how do you like them?